# How to handle ConcurrentModificationException while removing items in collection?

Tags: java

I am trying delete a `String` that occurs 5 times in my List. This is what I've tried:

```
for(String obj : list1)
{
    if(new ArzList().countOccurrence(list1, obj ) == 5)
    {
        list2.add(obj);
        list1.removeAll(Collections.singleton(obj));                
    }
   else{
        list3.add(obj);
        list1.removeAll(Collections.singleton(obj));
   }
}
```

But I get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` each time.

How do I solve it?

Comment: i want list with no duplicate values. I can explain again. If consider one list1. i wan to divide into two list like list2 & 3. list2 contains no duplicate and each of it occurred 5 times in list1. the same way list3 may have no duplicate and each of it occurred less than 5 times in list.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't iterate and remove through the same list.

Create a copy of the original list. Iterate through the original list but remove items from the copy version. Return the duplicate(copy) version of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You're not allowed to modify the data structure mid-way through an iterator.

You could just use a normal loop here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    String obj = list1.get(i);
    ...
}
```

Comment: why i did like this bcoz i want list with data which contains each datum with less tha 5 occurence in the list if so it will be removed totally. so give an other way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can only safely delete an element during a loop from a collection using the Iterator.

```
Iterator<String> myIterator = list1.iterator();

while(myIterator.hasNext()) {
    //add logic to search list and delete element here
 }
```

Comment: but i want list with no duplicate values. I can explain again

Comment: Your question didn't say that...

Comment: but i want list with no duplicate values. I can explain again. If consider one list1. i wan to divide into two list like list2 & 3. list2 contains no duplicate and each of it occurred 5 times in list1. the same way list3 may have no duplicate and each of it occurred less than 5 times in list.

Comment: have u got it. help to solve it. thanks in advace

Comment: Do you mean if a String appears 5 times in List1, copy it to List2, and if it appears less than 5 times, copy it to List3?

Comment: That's completely different from your original question, I can't help with this without showing some code.Maybe ask a new question, and "CC" me?